# Overflowing bar serie in apache echarts when using dataZoom

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I am using apache echarts version 5.2.2 for rendering a bar chart with datazooms for both cartesian axes. However I am finding an easy to reproduce bug with this code that can be found just in [the dataZoom documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom).

[image]

That is what happens when I apply an `inside` zoom to my bars, it ends up overflowing the space for the Y axis.

The code that produces this is the following, which can be pasted in the [echarts example page](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple):

```js
option = {
    dataZoom: [
        {
            id: 'dataZoomX',
            type: 'inside',
            xAxisIndex: [0],
            filterMode: 'filter'
        },
        {
            id: 'dataZoomY',
            type: 'inside',
            yAxisIndex: [0],
            filterMode: 'empty'
        }
    ],
    xAxis: {type: 'value'},
    yAxis: {type: 'value'},
    series: {
        type: 'bar',
        data: [
            // The first column corresponds to xAxis,
            // and the second column corresponds to yAxis.
            [12, 24, 36],
            [90, 80, 70],
            [3, 9, 27],
            [1, 11, 111]
        ]
    }
}
```

I have read the suggested configurations for the `filterMode` property, but this bug happens whether if I use `filter`, `weakFilter`, etc. I have also seen this work properly for other charts that have an X axis of type `category`, but mine is of type `value` and the `inside` zooms are mandatory.

Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: increase [z value](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.z) of yAxis?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like echarts places the bars as long as the center is inside the grid. I dont see an inbuild way around that currently. Here are some possible suggestions:

1. Use a combination of [`barMaxWidth`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.barMaxWidth) and [yAxis `offset`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.offset) to make space between bars and the yAxis. (Note, that for some reason a second yAxis is neccessary for `offset` to work properly).

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAmBDMWBawwAtgFywDaa6yV1sEGZA5NrgcQBpMA0t1YATxABTZhGgBnBsJ590ADwCC8iBICS0DMPllyABgC6vOugBmEADZhhAJwCywLc3NXbTPgF9j1VCfqNYFhx8QiIATVk_QRExSWlIkwFlVQ0tHQoARiM5WBdre0dRQOEicAF3Og8qbIVkiTIkWGiipgA3LAsAVxlYLyoklXqKRokAC2AAdzJTDolhXu5kWBBgKUgYZgthUzAeWGBTUzmwMgAmPV6a2DmbCGEh334hFoAjLBsE9AGUzW0yDO86De9iw8gA6gwwKMyAAWPSAzDBXTkDKnRanGFGcgATnhsAAHIZuOQAMyLbFYgGwDJZAxUKoeADcQA):

```js
option = {
  dataZoom: [
    {
      id: 'dataZoomX',
      type: 'inside',
      xAxisIndex: [0],
      filterMode: 'filter'
    },
    {
      id: 'dataZoomY',
      type: 'inside',
      yAxisIndex: [1],
      filterMode: 'empty'
    }
  ],
  xAxis: { type: 'value' },
  yAxis: [{ show: false }, { position: 'left', offset: 20 }],
  series: {
    type: 'bar',
    yAxisIndex: 1,
    barMaxWidth: 40,
    data: [[12, 24],[90, 80],[3, 9],[1, 11]]
  }
};
```

2. Use the [`dataZoom` event](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.datazoom) to adjust the data by yourself if its overlapping the axis.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3gNwQGwFcBTALkwEYAaGCigXQF8rcCTyMBmGgTiZbxEylAEw0RAFn6shHHgAYaADnlN6AbgBQmkAAcoAS3BoYWTTHhIEALRAgAth3MXTzlzANxyAckTJbDgAa3lRuLlAAnrrC3gaQnsQhYRYAHgCCKQYQAJJgcMQpHKqh7hYAZgb4UMQATgCyIPk-FVW13mHMYWalHl4wvlYB9gCaST2R0T5xEAljpREZWbn5hZT0JaUt1fWNMcT2-hHt7ozO687pmRDkWJ0WC1c3dzAQtQbE167uEzEARgg1OYWPwIcggjanRhabT2CIAYQAFgCoAA6cAACgG_js9hCMDKhDAwEMGN0AIQ9ggAEovjBQJBYKADuBiGAoBATLDEciUQB9Jm6FlsiB1BC6LQWenQGCXLImAVC9kYADyvwAVsRiSiANbECIQdEKsCs9lUlEVPLo3URNAAPhg1pRcWARHyBu8sog3ipVI0zilsGgyJMnr5vPsu3wKIQVxREGABGIfIK1TZGFUErp4Glrxq7w56FVGq1ghIBq5SJqqP5lfZot0VPTfos_uzsBAeYA5nEAAoGFLEfCc-G1lH0nC1KAAFRAfYH-HRWE9ywK5HkzBeyCrVMzAZg_xqAHVPFAEXPByZc_m-SC-fgEBEQIRUTMAF7ETOthkwY0AdwAIlYJgYM2-IdjAhptpYyCCnE7ZlNBCA0t0Lh7gecImrUuj9he6AVjy46TjO54Lkuiw5Hkq4wOuNAgrBbIoqWxBNjuYQGAh6LoZhNTYfOMAALQQQex5wKeJEwAA9DAIg0vaHYGN2YAkchySIfRqIGNU9gAMqRPgxAmIS-QWsQcCZhYjAwIOry0u4dEgHBTpabpET6SYWCgPgHY-FANQIJAZI1Ca3hQh0YR_oByAorohAQAi6L2XBrEWc4zj4VWcbEFAyr6EYYCLleHwcFgILkBFViMEwrGMFSQA):

```js
const data = [{value: [1, 11]},{value: [3, 9]},{value: [12, 24]},{value: [90, 80]}];

option = {
  dataZoom: [
    {
      id: 'dataZoomX',
      type: 'inside',
      xAxisIndex: [0],
      filterMode: 'filter'
    },
    {
      id: 'dataZoomY',
      type: 'inside',
      yAxisIndex: [1],
      filterMode: 'empty'
    }
  ],
  xAxis: {},
  yAxis: {},
  series: {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
  }
};


myChart.on('dataZoom', function(params) {
  const components = myChart._componentsMap;
  const xAxis = components[Object.keys(components).find(key => key.includes('xAxis'))];
  const start = xAxis.__model.axis.scale._extent[0];
  const series = Object.values(myChart._chartsMap)[0];
  
  const originPixel = myChart.convertToPixel({xAxisIndex: 0}, start);
  const barWidthPixel = series._data._layout.size;
  
  const newData = [];
  for (const datapoint of data) {
    const barCenterpixel = myChart.convertToPixel({xAxisIndex: 0}, datapoint.value[0]);
    if (barCenterpixel - (barWidthPixel / 2) > originPixel) {
      datapoint.itemStyle = undefined;
    } else {
      datapoint.itemStyle = {color: 'transparent'};
    }
    newData.push(datapoint);
  }
  
  myChart.setOption({series: [{data: newData}]});
})
```